# How do I use the DES Algorithm in .NET?

Tags: java, .net, des, encryption

How do I use `DES` in .NET?

Here's how I'd do it in Java:

```
        public static String decrypt(byte[] pin, byte [] desKeyData ) throws Exception {
    //if (ISOConstantsLibrary.DEBUG) System.out.println("original: " + pin + " key: " + ISOUtil.bcd2str(desKeyData, 0, 2 * desKeyData.length, false) );
    String out = "";

    try {           
        SecretKeySpec desKey = new SecretKeySpec(desKeyData, "DES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");//DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
        byte[] encrypted_password = pin;
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, desKey);
        byte[] decrypted_password = cipher.doFinal(encrypted_password);
        out = new String(decrypted_password);
        //if (ISOConstantsLibrary.DEBUG) System.out.println("Decrypted Password " + out);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return out;
}
```

Is there a library for decrypting `DES` encryption in .NET? If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is a stream

```
using System.Security.Cryptography

string key;
Stream input;
string output;
DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
//Set key and initialization vector for DES algorithm
DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

//Create CryptoStream layer to decrypt input on reading
CryptoStream decryptStream = new CryptoStream(input, DES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
//return decrypted
return new StreamReader(decryptStream ).ReadToEnd();
```

otherwise you can of course easily write the input into a stream.
For ECB mode you also need to set the Mode of the DES object to ECB:

```
DES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DESCryptoServiceProvider. See this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010).

Answer (score 1):

As a side note to complement the other answers. If you can, don't use it, use the [AESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

> DES is now considered to be insecure
>   for many applications. This is chiefly
>   due to the 56-bit key size being too
>   small; in January, 1999,
>   distributed.net and the Electronic
>   Frontier Foundation collaborated to
>   publicly break a DES key in 22 hours
>   and 15 minutes